# Can't pass useState() 'set' function to grand child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, use-state

I'm having issues trying to get my useState variable to work. I create the state in my grandparent then pass it into my parent. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
export function Grandparent(){

return(
    <div>
         const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState("0")
         <Parent setSelectedID2={setSelectedID} .../>  //(elipses just mean that I'm passing other params too)
    <div />
)}
```

Parent:

```
const Parent = ({setSelectedID2 ...}) => {

   return(
      <div>
          {setSelectedID2("5")}  //works
          <Child setSelectedID3={setSelectedID2} />
      </div>
   )
}
```

From the parent I can use 'setSelectedID2' like a function and can change the state. However, when I try to use it in the child component below I get an error stating 'setSelectedID3' is not a function. I'm pretty new to react so I'm not sure if I'm completely missing something. Why can I use the 'set' function in parent but not child when they're getting passed the same way?

Child:

```
const Child = ({setSelectedID3 ...}) => {
    
    return(
        <div >
            {setSelectedID3("10")} //results in error
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error you get please?

Comment: Why are you creating and calling these functions in the return block? You should put them above your return.

Comment: The error is: TypeError: setSelectedID3 is not a function

Comment: @ToddSkelton I called it in the return block as I'm planning on linking it to an onClick function within a returned div in the child component. I was just trying to get the 'set' function working first.

Comment: Not sure where you doing mistake, I have tried to create a example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hp6qv2), Check it out. If it still don't work, feel free to update and try to reproduce the same on link

Comment: Did you try passing it inside a function like setSelectedID3={ () => setSelectedID2 }

Comment: There's something different between your real code and the example above as the example above would work

Comment: After looking at your stackblitz example, you can't just call the setter function in your render function. It needs to be on some event, click handler etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example with everything you have listed here. Props are passed and the function is called in each.

You don't need to name your props 1,2,3.., they are scoped to the function so it's fine if they are the same.

I moved `useState` and function calls above the return statement, because that's where that logic should go in a component. The `jsx` is only used for logic dealing with your display/output.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-tree-uiqw5?file=/src/App.js

Also, I created a working example with a `onClick` since that's what you will be doing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-violet-dt897?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return <Grandparent />;
}

const Grandparent = () => {
  const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState("0");
  return (
    <div>
      {selectedID}
      <Parent setSelectedID={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ selectedID, setSelectedID }) => {
  setSelectedID("5");
  return (
    <div>
      {selectedID}
      <Child setSelectedID={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ selectedID, setSelectedID }) => {
  setSelectedID("10");
  return <div>{selectedID}</div>;
};
```

**output**

```
10
10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

In React you make your calculations within the components/functions (it's the `js` part) and then what you return from them is JSX (it's the `html` part).

```
export function Grandparent(){

const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState("0");

return(
    <div>
         <Parent setSelectedID2={setSelectedID} .../>  //(elipses just mean that I'm passing other params too)
    <div />
)}
```

You can also use (but not define!) some `js` variables in JSX, as long as they are "renderable" by JSX (they are not Objects - look for React console warnings).

That's your React.101 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState("0")
```

should be outside return